# Implicitly convert a vector to a list in C++

Tags: c++, list, vector, type-conversion

```
// Было так:
[&server](const std::string &query) {
    return server.MethodFopDocuments(query); // возвращает std::vector<Document>
});

// Нужно так:
[&server](const std::string &query) {
    std::vector<Document> v = server.MethodFopDocuments(query); // возвращает std::vector<Document>
    std::list<Document> l(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v.end()));
    return l;
});
```

Нужно чтобы лямбда вместо вектора (как в первом коде) возвращала список (как во втором коде). Но приходится делать много лишних движений - создавать промежуточный вектор v, чтобы получить итераторы на его начало и конец. Можно ли оптимизировать лямбду со списком, чтобы избавиться от промежуточного вектора и возвращать список одной строкой return, как в первом коде?

Comment: Всегда ли, чтобы получить итераторы начала и конца контейнера, нужно обязательно предварительно создать этот контейнер? Нельзя объединить это в одну операцию?

Comment: А смысл? Вектор-то все равно создается. Хотите сэкономить на вводе строки?